# Foce download file using PHP

Tags: php, download

I would like to run a download window instead of reading a MP3 file on browser, so I used the following script:

direct_download.php

```
$file = $_GET['file'];

$file = basename($file);

header ("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$file.";");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
readfile($siteURLHTTPServer1.'Downloads/Medias/'.$rub.'/'.$srub.'/'.$cat.'/'.$scat.'/'.$tilawa_type.$riwaya_type.'/MP3/'.$file);
exit();
```

download_link:

```
echo '<a href="Files/direct_download.php?file='.$domainSite.'_'.$scat.$num_pad.'.mp3" id="'.$id.'" style="cursor: pointer;" target="_BLANK"><img src="'.$path2icons.'Download32_32.png" class="embedDownload masterTooltip" width="25" height="25" align="absmiddle" /></a>';
```

so how can I do to specify the full path of download file, knowing that my files are located as bellow:

- site.com/download/mp3/file.mp3
- site.com/files/direct_download.php
- site.com/files/download_link.php

Thanks in advance

Comment: You could point directly to your files. As a note: your script has a huge security hole. You can download any file with the script above, not only mp3 files.

Comment: Let's say you file path is `site.com/download/mp3/file.mp3`. Let's say you want to log how many downloads this file has, user ip address, etc, you could point to a php file, log everything you need, then redirect the user to the actual filepath `site.com/download/mp3/file.mp3`. Please say what you need to do.

Comment: by clicking on a link, an Ajax query is sent and log all info (downloads, ip, update DBs...), so the only point I have, that I cannot download the file, it is giving me a dialog box to download with 0KB http://s29.postimg.org/gln43zqt3/Screenshot_from_2014_07_16_14_38_40.png

Comment: You probably didn't passed a valid path. Just print `var_dump(file_exist($_GET['file'])); exit;` before `$file = $_GET['file'];`. If the result is false, the path doesn't exist.

Comment: well, I used curl instead, now what I am trying is to use Ajax:
url: "download.php", and download code is:
set_time_limit(0);
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"); 
    header("Cache-Control: private",false);
    header("Content-Type: application/download"); 
    header("Content-Disposition: filename=$fileName");

    $ch = curl_init($path2file);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);        
    exit();
but the download doesnt go through, hence using it like download?file='', it goes

Comment: If the files are already on the same server, don't use curl. And please edit your question and put the code there as `later edit` or something.

Comment: cannot edit the code, my files are on other server, why don't use cuRL, allow_url_open is OFF for me